# No sound on headphones with sof-hda-dsp audio on ubuntu (and variants)

Tags: sound

When using the `sof-hda-dsp` driver, I have no sound from my laptop on any of the Ubuntu variants.

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-37-generic
```

From `alsamixer`:

```
Card: sof-hda-dsp
Chip: Realtek ALC3204
```

Answer (score 2):

Bizarrely, changing the Input device to `Headset Mono Microphone` suddenly causes the output device to start working. I'm not sure why, but I thought this would be helpful to anyone to encounters this (if you know why, please let me know)

Comment: Oposity behaviour here. Any idea why?

Comment: Same funny phenomenon here, on dell precision 3560 with realtek alc3204

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 - sound stopped working on built-in speaker and audio jack. It was working only on USB headset.

The only procedure that helped me is described on this page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status || ubuntu-security-status
sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

And then reboot.

Comment: Your answer solved my issue, namely the `sudo apt install puvacontrol` part. For some reason PA was trying to access some headphones mic while no headphones are connected.

Comment: @Vorac I think you meant `sudo apt install pavucontrol`  Regardless, this didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

I have added this line -

`options snd-hda-intel model=auto`

to

`/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

and it started working for me. Apparently, we need to point out alsamixer to use auto-detection between speaker and headphones.

Comment: I have used below option to fix my headset issue in Dell G5 15   
`options snd-hda-intel index=-2`