# sof-hda-dsp sound issues

Tags: drivers, sound, updates, headphones

So, I noticed that plugging in my headphones today and yesterday didn't do anything. The headphones weren't recognized (i.e. I had no option to select if they were headphones or headset or mic) and there was no sound coming from them. I tried this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/109931/audio-jack-not-working-properly-in-ubuntu), but that didn't help. I can get my sound back by selecting the headphone microphone "sof-hda-dsp" as input, strangely enough, as in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253498/no-sound-on-headphones-with-sof-hda-dsp-audio-on-ubuntu-and-variants), but I'm still not able to select what kind of device I plugged in. Moreover, when I remove the headphones again, the sound does not come through the speakers.
I would like things the way they were before...

By the way, the name "sof-hda-dsp" is not something I've seen before. Could it be a driver update? I checked my synaptic history, but I think it's incorrect. There's only history from last february, but I obviously did updates since then.

I'm working with Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell laptop. Any other info that would be useful?

EDIT: sometimes the headphones don't work at all and the sound only comes from the speakers OR when it does miraculously start working again it sounds noisy and the high frequencies are filtered out (I think)