# Speakers stop working shortly after install

Tags: sound, lenovo, speakers

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.10 on a Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 (model 82A3005RUK).  The speakers worked fine at first, but then after a short while stopped working; all they do is periodically make a 'pop' followed by a whimper.  After I switched to using the 5.8.0-25 kernel they worked again, but then stopped working shortly afterwards in the same way.

The sound works fine with USB or bluetooth headphones.  I don't know whether the headphone jack works, I don't have a pair of headphones to try it with.

I tried restarting pulseaudio and also installing pavucontrol, neither of which helped (the speaker appears to be playing sound, from the point of view of pavucontrol).

Let me know if there is any further information I can provide -- I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

For now the third answer here [No sound on headphones with sof-hda-dsp audio on ubuntu (and variants)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253498/no-sound-on-headphones-with-sof-hda-dsp-audio-on-ubuntu-and-variants) seems to have worked.

> I have added this line -
>
> `options snd-hda-intel model=auto`
>
> to
>
> `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
>
> and it started working for me. Apparently, we need to point out alsamixer to use auto-detection between speaker and headphones.